# Como puedo añadir una imagen a un celda especifica a un Excel utilizando MS Visual Basic?

Tags: visual-studio, excel, vba

estoy realizando un programa que se centra en ir editando un Excel desde un programa realizado en Visual Studio con Visual Basic como lenguaje, pero no se como podría añadir una imagen cargada desde el programa a una celda especifica de mi documento en Excel.

```
        Dim puesto As String = CStr(TextBox1.Text)
        Dim cantidadpuesto As String = CStr(TextBox2.Text)
        Dim recomendaciones As String = CStr(TextBox4.Text)
        Dim observaciones As String = CStr(TextBox5.Text)
        Dim vigencia As String = CStr("Fecha de vigencia: " & TextBox6.Text)
        Dim revision As String = CStr("Fecha de ultima revisión: " & TextBox7.Text)

        Libro.Sheets(1).Cells(6, 4) = puesto
        Libro.Sheets(1).Cells(6, 16) = cantidadpuesto
        Libro.Sheets(1).Cells(11, 14) = recomendaciones
        Libro.Sheets(1).Cells(22, 8) = observaciones
        Libro.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 14) = vigencia
        Libro.Sheets(1).Cells(3, 14) = revision

        SaveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "*.xlsx"
        SaveFileDialog1.FileName = "Nombre"
        SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "Archivos de Excel (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx"
        SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

        Libro.SaveAs(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
```

Aqui un ejemplo de como he estado tomando datos y colocándolos en mi Excel

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. Si no recuerdo mal no puedes insertar una imagen en una celda. Las imágenes en una hoja excel son tratadas como objetos y en una celda no puedes insertar un objeto (que alguien me corrija si me equivoco).

Lo que si puedes hacer es insertar la URL de una imagen y que el usuario, haciendo click sobre esa URL, acceda a la imagen.

Esa URL puede ser de una foto guardada en el equipo o bien de una foto en internet.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, tienes que insertar la imagen en Excel. Supongo que estará en algún sitio, o en el propio portapapeles, pero para insertar una imagen, puedes usar algo similar a esto:

`ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(ruta)`

Excel la insertará donde quiera, pero luego puedes hacer un bucle hasta localizarla, cortar y pegar en la celda que te interese:

```
Dim Imag As Shape

For Each Imag In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    Imag.Cut
    Range("F25").PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
Next Imag
```

Esto hará que la **esquina superior izquierda** esté en la celda F25. Pero si la imagen es más grande, tapará más celdas, así que tienes que cambiar el alto de fila y el ancho de columna si quieres ajustarla.

PAra todo eso, mira el objeto `Shape` y sus propiedades, porque te pueden ayudar en tu código.

> [Objeto
>   SHAPE](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/excel.shapes)